# VPN: Can login when connected through wifi but not when connected through cable

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, vpn, ethernet

When at home I use a VPN connection to connect to the campus network.
I used to be able to connect through ethernet, but now I can only connect when I am online through wifi. I have not changed anything in my setup (afaik).

Console tells me:

```
24-02-16 00:27:10,883 racoon[33025]: IPSec connecting to server [<IP address>]
24-02-16 00:27:10,883 racoon[33025]: IPSec Phase 1 started (Initiated by me).
24-02-16 00:27:10,966 racoon[33025]: IPSec Phase 1 established (Initiated by me).
24-02-16 00:27:11,031 racoon[33025]: IPSec connecting to server [<IP address>]
24-02-16 00:27:11,031 racoon[33025]: IPSec Phase 1 started (Initiated by me).
24-02-16 00:27:11,091 racoon[33025]: IPSec Phase 1 established (Initiated by me).
24-02-16 00:27:21,031 racoon[33025]: IPSec disconnecting from server [<IP address>]
24-02-16 00:27:21,032 racoon[33025]: IPSec disconnecting from server [<IP address>]
```

I am able to connect to other VPN services using cable.

Any suggestions on where to start looking? I am using OSX 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

I would look for an IP address conflict, ie maybe the IP address of your ethernet Interface is interfering with the VPN addresses.

Comment: My wifi and ethernet IP addresses come from the same pool. Would this not argue against this?

Comment: It would, however it is still the most plausible explanation based on the information you have provided - ie in a "nothing changed" scenario - and, while unlikely in itself, its definately possible. Try statically defining the IP address and see what happens.  If that fails, the next candidate to look into (after Firewalls) is MTU issues - but again, why would these occur suddenly.